# How to change layer transparency of wms layer in arcgis android sdk

Tags: wms, android, arcgis-online, arcgis-android

I wish to overlay a transparent WMS layer onto a basemap in arcgis android. Here is my code snippet. It loads only the BaseMap but not the WMS layer, i tried on Online Arcgis and it works.

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


m_MapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer tileLayer;
        WMSLayer weatherlayer = new WMSLayer ("http://wms.openweathermap.org/service?");    

tileLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D/MapServer");
        Envelope env = new Envelope(103.5, 1.52,
               104.22, 1.18);
        m_MapView.setExtent(env);
        m_MapView.addLayer(tileLayer);

        String[] layers = {"precipitation"}; 
        weatherlayer.setVisibleLayer(layers);
        weatherlayer.setOpacity(0.5f);
        m_MapView.addLayer(weatherlayer);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with the service url string, you don't need the **?** appended at the end:

```
// set up the wms url
wmsURL = "http://wms.openweathermap.org/service";
wmsLayer = new WMSLayer(wmsURL);
wmsLayer.setImageFormat("image/png");
// available layers
String[] visibleLayers = {"clouds", "precipitation"};
wmsLayer.setVisibleLayer(visibleLayers);
wmsLayer.setOpacity(0.5f);
mMapView.addLayer(wmsLayer);
```

We have a sample using this service in our Gradle based sample on [Github](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-android-sdk-gradle-samples).  Check out the [WMSLayer](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-android-sdk-gradle-samples/tree/master/WmsLayer) specifically.